# Darwin/Linux/Unix command line email client that supports iCloud?

Tags: software-recommendation, icloud, email, command-line, imap

I need to access my iCloud email from a command line.

Is there a command line client for Mac OS X (and/or Linux and/or Unix) that can connect to Apple's (I assume it is IMAP) servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A popular command line e-mail clients is [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/). Use a package manager such as Brew or Macports to install it on MacOS. Have a look at [this page](http://jstorimer.com/shells/2010/01/19/using-mutt-with-gmail-on-osx.html) for some pointers.

You can find the IMAP settings for iCloud in [this Support article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4864).

Comment: Sorry. Overlooked this answer for a long time. In fact it is exactly the correct answer.